# Use two Hikvision camera in one form delphi

Tags: delphi, camera

I want to Play two videos from IP cameras on a Delphi form i wrote a function and it is correct when i use one camera in a form but when i use two cameras only one camera is play what happen for camera?

```
  CAMERA := Tcamera.Create;
  CAMERA.PlayVideo(Panel7, MainForm.EntryCameraIP, MainForm.EntryPassword);
  CAMERA.Free;
  CAMERA1:=Tcamera.Create;
  CAMERA1.PlayVideo(Panel4, MainForm.ExitCameraIP, MainForm.ExitPassword);
  CAMERA1.Free;
```

Comment: You are using only one camera object... and the reusing it. The most this can do is to show one video after the other. If you want them to work at the same time, you certainly need to use two distinct variables.

Comment: @Frazz, but when i use two distinct variables they can not work at the same time

Comment: Neither can one... you still create the second after the first has been destroyed. I've never used TCamera, but I am 100% sure that with that kind of code you will never have the two objects doing what they do at the same time... simply because they do not exist both in the same instant. If TCamera does not have a fire and forget play mode, then you'll have to look into threads, I suppose.